# Unsigned types to Java

Tags: java, byte

Could anyone please tell me how to convert the unsigned char '0' to a byte in Java ?

Thank you

Comment: Is that the character '0' or "unsigned char whatever = 0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can covert it two ways depending on what you are trying to do

```
char ch = '0';
byte b = (byte) ch; // ASCII value of '0'
```

or

```
byte b = (byte) (ch - '0'); // numeric value of 0
```

or

```
byte b = (byte) Character.getNumericValue(ch); // numeric value.
```

The last one is interesting because it gives you the numeric value of all characters, not just '0' .. '9'

```
for (int ch = Character.MIN_VALUE; ch < Character.MAX_VALUE; ch++) {
    int value = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
    if (value > 99)
        System.out.println("The numeric value for " + (char) ch + " is " + value);
}
```

prints

```
The numeric value for ௱ is 100
The numeric value for ௲ is 1000
The numeric value for ፻ is 100
The numeric value for ፼ is 10000
The numeric value for Ⅽ is 100
The numeric value for Ⅾ is 500
The numeric value for Ⅿ is 1000
The numeric value for ⅽ is 100
The numeric value for ⅾ is 500
The numeric value for ⅿ is 1000
The numeric value for ↀ is 1000
The numeric value for ↁ is 5000
The numeric value for ↂ is 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how we interpret the question, I guess; but simple is often best:

```
byte b = 0;
```

This is assuming the quotes around your 0 are for emphasis, not part of the syntax!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly typecast it as follows

```
byte bValue = (byte)c;
```

Where c is character you want to convert to byte.